# std::shared_ptr<FILE> display to textbrowser?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I want to ask that, I have `std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(_popen(command.c_str(),"r"), _pclose);`
in my `bool exec(std::string command){` function.

My question is, how can I display on textbrowser, `std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(_popen(command.c_str(),"r"), _pclose);`?

Normally  `ui->textBrowser->setText();`  used for displaying textBrowser but it doesnt work in bool exec function.

Comment: Why use `_popen` and `_pclose`?  Since you're already using `Qt` you might want to look at [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) instead.

Comment: and also qt has [QSharedPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html)